# Unable to loop through elements inside an HTML string using JQuery 2.1.4

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a JQuery function to retrieve a string containing some HTML code and process it locally. The string is:

```
var return_data = '<div><tr><td>blah</td><td>more blah</td></tr><tr><td>blah</td><td>more blah</td></tr><tr><td>blah</td><td>more blah</td></tr><span id="morerows">1</span></div>';
```

(I understand `<tr>` should come inside `<table>` and not inside `<div>` but this is how I need the input for some reason and that should be inconsequential to the issue at hand.)
What I need is to loop through each `<tr>` and output the contents to the console. I am trying this:

```
$(return_data).find("tr").each(function(){
  var myData = $(this).html();
  console.log(myData);
});
```

But the above does nothing; no output on the console. Just to be sure, I changed the `console.log()` input to simply "hello" and turns out, the control isn't even entering the loop. What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: What shows console.log($(this));?

Comment: No point doing `console.log($(this))` if the loop isn't being entered to begin with. That's what I said in the question as well. Even a `console.log("hello")` didn't execute.

Comment: the `tr`s are ignored because they make no sense in a div.

Comment: Nope, they shouldn't be ignored because to JQuery, they should just be another element within an element.

Comment: A `console.log($(return_data));` shows that there is only text and the span in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need the following. Wrap `tr`s with a `table` and loop through the `tr`s instead of `div`.

```
var return_data = '<div><table><tr><td>blah</td><td>more blah</td></tr><tr><td>blah</td><td>more blah</td></tr><tr><td>blah</td><td>more blah</td></tr></table><span id="morerows">1</span></div>';

$(return_data).find("tr").each(function () {
    var myData = $(this).html();
    console.log(myData);
});
```

Comment: I cannot use the <table> tag because I already have an existing table on page to which these rows need to be appended. That's why I am only receiving the rows from the server.

Comment: `tr` cannot be nested inside `div`. It will not even been rendered if you not use `table`. @TheLearner

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `<table>` tag in ur html, try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sr7oegsz/)

```
 var return_data = '<div><table><tr><td>blah</td><td>more blah</td></tr><tr><td>blah</td><td>more blah</td></tr><tr><td>blah</td><td>more blah</td></tr></table><span id="morerows">1</span></div>';
```

Comment: The <table> tag is not missing...I don't have it for a reason. Please see the edit in my question.